# How to make my opencart site as password protected

Tags: php, opencart

My opencart website is under construction.I want to show the coming soon(construction) page as public and make the opencart index.php and other sub pages of the site visible to only password protected users.How can i get this?

How it is possible to show the construction index.html page as public and other index.php(opencart root folder page)and other pages as private.

[password-protect](http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/password-protect.php)

Comment: This is probably more of an Apache option, like adding a .htaccess file to the directory.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: Opencart force login doesn't match my requirement.kindly go through my requirement once again@shadyyx

Answer (score 0):

Put .htaccess in the root of the site

1.Generate htpasswd here: http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

2.Then put this in your .htacces:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

(you only need to change “/path/to/.htpasswd” with the full path to your .htpasswd.)

Comment: Already .htacess is in the root of the site.Kindly suggest any other solution.@CroiOS

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Hi by using htpasswd generator i am just getting the code.how can i create the htpasswd file@CroiOS

Comment: @RamaPriya - you can create passwd file over ftp editor ot notepad and then upload over filezila or some similar program

Comment: What is the file extension for htpasswd file.If i have placed my .htpasswd file in the root folder.what is the path i have to mention here.AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd@CroiOS

Comment: Finally i have got it.Thank you but what about logout?@CroiOS

Answer (score 0):

if you put the script online you could settle it up by using " Password Protect Directories " facility from cpanel.

you could select the folder / your root opencart website and set a password..

you must wrap your opencart script into folder first and set your coming soon page in your web root. then you could use cpanel facility to set password in your opencart folder.

Comment: what is the script i need to use?can you share that opencart script?@vcless